# No keyboard layouts are installed on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, layout

Hello I just installed an Ubuntu12.04 64 bit system.

I am using gnome classic but I don't think this is related to my problem.

The problem is that during the installation (or just after I don't remember)
I was informed by the installer that some packets where not able to be installed.

I just ignored it.

The problem is that I had selected Greek for keyboard layout so when i tried to change the input method nothing happened.

I went to keyboard `preferences->input` method and it seems that I cannot add anything (add button is disabled) only thing i can select is input method to be Chinese or something, but I cannot add a layout....

Answer (score 2):

Ok problem solved

I had to add it from keyboard layout settings using Unity.
Now it works in GNOME too

After that I installed `gkbd-capplet` needed by gnome so I could use the `gkbd-keyboard-layout` when right clicking on the applet.

Thanks @Gunnar Hjalmarsson for his valuable help

Answer (score 1):

These commands might fix it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

Ok. I'm not sure what 12.04 gnome classic looks like exactly, but I have a feeling that your problem is that you don't find the keyboard layout GUI. One possibility, of course, is to temporarily switch to the standard Ubuntu desktop...

Comment: Nop tried didnt do anything... Im up to date....

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what 12.04 gnome classic looks like exactly, but I have a feeling that your problem is that you don't find the keyboard layout GUI. One possibility, of course, is to temporarily switch to the standard Ubuntu desktop...